# my regEx is not deleting line as required

Tags: regex

I have a regEx in awk and i want it to delete a certain line containing " failure3" but it doesnt work, i have tried, java, sed and awk but none of them seem to be working

so the context its looking at is something like this:

```
service 1 monitored_by failure3
service 2 monitored_by failure1
```

I want it to delete the whole first line or any line that contains "failure3": my regEx is as follows:

```
awk '/failure3/'>
```

or

```
perl -pi -e 'undef $_ if /failure3/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip the lines which contains the string `failure3`in awk,

```
$ awk '!/failure3/' file
service 2 monitored_by failure1
```

OR

Through sed,

```
sed '/failure3/d' file
```

Comment: just tried that it didnt do anything..Am i meant to also include service 2 monitored_by? what if i dont want to hard-code that part

Comment: did you want to delete the lines which contains `failure3` or `service 2 monitored_by` ? If yes then try this `awk '!/failure3|service 2 monitored_by/' file`